# Caching results temporarily for multiple aggregations

Tags: caching, clickhouse

I have the following query:

with result as (select * from  where filter) select count(col1) FROM result UNION ALL select count(col2) FROM result ...

All the aggregations have to compute the result which is a waste of resources. Is there any way to cache the results of the first query that can be used in the aggregations ? As the filter includes time range the user can provide time ranges, I am unable to pre-compute the "result" and hence all the aggregations.

I have tried variations in how the aggregations are performed but it does not help because the biggest time spent is in obtaining the "result".

Comment: Use a temporary table for that. You must be familiar with how to do this depending on the client you use. Another way is some permanent table use (say, with engine=memory), but it requires you to drop such a table when it's not needed eventually, which may not be convenient.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried creating a temporary table like this: 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result as select * from table' and then tried using the table but i get the error "Table not found". I tried using it in the same session but still does not seem to work.

Comment: There was a typo in my command. Your suggestion worked. Thanks !